# What could prevent me from using the Steam Market?

Tags: steam

I have this account on steam. I want to sell CS:GO items using this account after 15 days when the Steam Guard Restriction is over. Can I sell or will it still have a restriction so that I can't use this to sell the items? I mean My friend reckons there will be a restriction that I have to buy anything from Steam Store in the last 365 days [except the last 30 days] to use market. Will this restriction be there?
[image: Transaction History]
[image: Wallet Balance]

### EDIT:

I have another question regarding the same account. Can I redeem a USD wallet code in this account? I am from India and we don't have direct payment method to steam so we have to use Wallet Codes to get around that. Can I redeem a 5$ code in this account?

### UPDATE:

To my second question (the new edit), I got a clear answer. Yes I can use USD wallet codes but the currency will converted to EUR first, if I change the country to a valid country where the code was bought and use the client from that country.

Comment: Your "edit" part is not directly related to the initial question. I suggest you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try clicking that [FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214) link at the end there? Your question is [perfectly answered](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214#eligibleparticipants) there...

> **Who is eligible to participate in the Community Market?**
>
> **The account must have a successful purchase older than thirty days,
>   but not older than a year.** Also, Steam Guard must be enabled for 15
>   days.
>
> If you have had your password reset by Steam Support you will need to
>   wait another 15 days with Steam Guard enabled before you can list
>   items on the Community Market.
>
> If a chargeback has occurred on your account you will be eligible 30
>   days after your next successful purchase.
>
> If a password is reset on an active account, the market will be
>   restricted for 5 days. If an account has not been active within the
>   past two months, this restriction will last for 30 days. this does not
>   affect password changes, only password resets.
>
> Adding a new purchase method to an account will trigger a market
>   restriction for seven days.

Comment: To be fair that's not the clearest piece of text I've ever read in my life. :)

Comment: I've updated the question, will be grateful if you can answer that too! :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no restriction after those 15 days - I have known people with no games in their accounts that just trade and people who only have F2P games and sell on the marketplace.

You will be able to sell on the marketplace as soon as your 15 days are up as long as you have steamguard.